# Oracle Migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to migrate SQL Sever to Oracle. Since Oracle only allow 30 bytes as the column name, some columns whose name is longer than 30 are shorten to 30, and Oracle also changed some columns' names to avoid two columns with same name.

For example, there are two columns example_XXXX_test, and example_XXXX_test_column. To make the column name no longer than 30, Oracle would cut them to example_XXXX_tes(suppose it's 30 chars) and example_XXX_t15. I'm wondering where is that number(15) from? I'm sure it's not a sequence number or column ID, and I couldn't find anything from Oracle docs.

Comment: Can you wait to do your migration? 12.2 will offer support for longer table names and you won't have to re-write any of your application code. I think we have some internal counter when changing up the column names.

Comment: I hope I can wait, but it's a request from client ......

Comment: I can't give you a 12.2 availability date either, so I can't tell you or your client how long you'd have wait - unless you were going to host their database on our Oracle Cloud DBaaS - where 12.2 is ready in production today.

Comment: Which method/tool are you using to migrate your SQL Server table to Oracle? It is possible that if you are using some third party tool then that will rename the column and put the numeric value 15 at the end of converted column name. If you are using SQL Developer for migration, then you can check the column names in the captured model and converted model to see where and when it gets that numeric 15 value.